# JPQL join fetch if not null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

There are two entities: position and employee.

The goal is to get an employee with or without a position.
This query works if a position exists, but will throw an error if doesn't exist.

How to change this query to receive an employee if the employee has or hasn't a position?

```
public Employee getEmployee(Long id) {
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Employee employee;
    try {
        employee = em.createQuery("select e " +
                "from Employee e " +
                "join fetch e.position p " +
                "where e.employeeId= :id)", Employee.class)
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .getSingleResult();

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (NoResultException ex){
        throw new RuntimeException("MAMA mia");
    }
    return employee;
}


 @Entity
 @Table(name = "position")
 public class Position {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "POSITION_ID", updatable = false)
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "NAME")
     private String name;

     @JoinTable(name = "Position_Employee_JT")
     @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL)
     private Set<Employee employeeSet = new HashSet<();
 }



 @Entity
 @Table(name = "employee")
 public class Employee {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", updatable = false)
     private Long employeeId;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
     private Position position;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need fetch.LAZY and cascade.ALL? You have put them in strange places indicating you don't really understand what they are doing. Reevaluate those as a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use an inner join. Use a left join instead like this:

```
    employee = em.createQuery("select e " +
            "from Employee e " +
            "left join fetch e.position p " +
            "where e.employeeId= :id)", Employee.class)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
If you use fetch Lazy, the proxy will work for you!

Spring Data won't work and will throw an error:
Optional employee = repository.findById(id);

It works fine.

```
public Employee getEmployee(Long id) {
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class,id);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return employee;
}
```

Explanation here:
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-a-jpa-proxy-work-and-how-to-unproxy-it-with-hibernate/